# Доступ к комментариям HTML

Tags: html, javascript, комментарии

Есть ли какая-то возможность взаимодействия с HTML комментариями посредствам JS?

```
<div><!--Камент-->простотекст</div>
```

P.s. не надо говорить, что лучше использовать display:none. Мне просто чисто **теоретически** интересно именно взаимодейсвтие с комментами.

Comment: Я так думаю, не нужно закрывать отвеченные вопросы. ХэшКод, как и его идейный папа StackOverflow, это, все-таки, вики. Возможно, через какое-то время что-то поменяется — тогда кто-нибудь придет и добавит новую информацию.

Comment: хорошо, не буду. ^^

Comment: @drdaeman, а зачем тогда опция закрыть с вариантом ("Ответ получен и принят") ? В чём вообще суть закрытия? Они же никуда не исчезают?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/E4gC9/2/) пример. jquery там не обязателен, так для мнимого удобства.

С вашего позволения:

```
<div><!--comment 1-->text3<span>test</span><!--comment2--></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").each(function(){

    child = this.firstChild;
    while (child){

    // determine the type of the node
    switch (child.nodeType){
      // if the node is a comment node, output its value
      case Node.COMMENT_NODE : alert(child.nodeValue); break;
    }

    // move to the next child node
    child = child.nextSibling;

  }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Я ничего не имею против jQuery. :)
Для всех, кто против есть метка [pure_js][1]


  [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/pure_js/

Comment: Я на самом деле пытался выяснить сможет ли jquery отработать на комментариях - не смог. как кусок html'я видит($("div").html() в данном примере комменты выдаст) , но работать как с query не может ($(child).text() выдаст null, и replaceWith тоже не сработает).

Comment: @knes, я категорически против умножения сущностей без нужды, т.е. тэга `[pure_js]`.

Comment: Без нужды никто и не предлагает. Однако, тэг JS не может полностью донести до отвечающего конкретику вопроса. Ярые противники использования фреймворков имеют теперь реальную возможность отфильтровать то, что они видеть не хотят.
Те, кто хочет решение проблемы пишет js, кто хочет решение именно на jquery(или других фреймворках), пишет их, кроме обобщающего js. Те, кто не хочет связываться со сторонними библиотеками, обращает на данный факт внимание описанным выше тэгом.

Comment: @knes, это не будет работать. Те, кто интересуется `[javascript]` (именно так, а не `[js]`) и не игнорирует (например) `[jquery]` всё равно вопрос прочитают. 

Действительно, о каком пуризме может идти речь, если в 95% случаев JavaScript связан с конкретной DOMImplementation?

Comment: Вот как раз javascript я бы объединил с js. Во-первых, писать короче, во вторых, имхо, о 'java' пора бы уже начать забывать. Ошибки молодости, такие ошибки.
Последнее утверждение, если честно, не очень понятно. Как раз-таки когда приходится задумываться о конкретной модели, не полагаясь на сторонние реализации, мы и начинаем чувствовать тот самый чистый JS.

Answer (score 8):

чёрт, не успел:

```
 $('div').contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE)
    {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
 });
```

- [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: Вполне успел. =Ъ
Хотя, тот ответ более подробный и чуть больше отвечает вопросу.